# What would happen if i used alert(element) in javascript?

Tags: javascript

it always just shows 'null'. im trying to find out what happens when you enter alert(element), not alert(element.id) or any other attribute, but an actual element like a button or a td.

Comment: Then it's not an element, but  `null`

Comment: Try it! What would you expect?

Comment: I tried it, it said "[object HTMLDivElement]", not null.

Answer (score 2):

Then it's not an element, but  `null`. If it really was an element, it would call `.toString()` on it, which results in a string like `"[object HTMLDivElement]"`

Answer (score 0):

If passed to [`alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.alert), it will be casted to a string before put in an alert box. Casting DOM element to strings will usually invoke [`Object.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString), so you will see something like `"[object HTMLSomeElement]"`.

If you see `null` instead, it is likely that you didn't really select a DOM element as your `element` variable had the value `null` (less likely: something else whose string representatio is `"null"`). This could be if you called `document.getElementById` (or the like) before the DOM was actually loaded, it returns `null` if no element was found.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="element"></div>
<script>
var element = document.getElementById("element");
alert(element);
</script>
```

It will show [Object HTMLDivElement] instead of null, can you make it clearer what is element on your context is ?